# the application which made on android studio is not opening in my an

Tags: java

```
 2019-09-29 18:21:14.631 17496-17496/com.vssquare.testapp1
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

 Process: com.vssquare.testapp1, PID: 17496
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(252169968bytes) bitmap.
    at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:229)
    at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:97)
    at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:529)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Check Your Images Bytes I Guess Its Too Large If you are using any images in drawable folder then rename that last 24 specified files.